# How to debug app services azure

Tags: azure, atom-editor, azure-web-app-service

I created app service running on nodejs in azure, how to debug nodejs on azure by atom editor?

I saw a lot of tutorial that explain how to debug with visual studio but I prefer atom.

Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 1):

If Atom can hook into **[node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector)** (Azure App Service uses [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) which includes **node-inspector**) then you've set yourself up for a neat debugging experience.

See this URL to get started:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/08/19/debug-node-js-web-apps-on-azure/

Here's more on **node-inspector** (the screenshots seem to have vanished, even so it makes for a solid read from the iisnode author himself):
https://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/11/debug-nodejs-applications-on-windows.html